# How to send an ArrayList of packageName of apps to another activity?

Tags: android

I am able to send the package name using this code. But how can I start the new app by using its package name?

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            //CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView) view;

            //if(item.isChecked()){
            packageName = list.get(position).activityInfo.packageName;
            Log.i("PACKAGE", packageName);
            //TODO: Pass this packageName to a method
            finalList.add(packageName);
            //}else if(!item.isChecked()){
            //}
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do You want start new activity with it? Have You tried http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html extras?

Comment: use Intents by sending extras . refer the docs

Comment: So I should create a bundle and put this in that and use intent.putextras(bundle)? Will it send the package name?

Comment: I tried ArrayList<String> finalList; and finalList.add(packageName); under TODO comment but when I click on any item it gives me error java nullpointerexception

Comment: So I referred the logcat and it seems the error is for that line finalList.add(packageName). Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to show you how to [send and receive implicit intents](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html). This is useful for sending data to one or many activities, services or broadcast receivers and also between apps. The downside is that it is a 'public' intent (if you do not use the LocalBroadcastManager) so don't send any sensitive information.

1. Create a send-method that the sender uses.
2. Modify the AndroidManifest.xml for the receiving entity (In your case an Activity)
3. Modify the receiving entity to handle the incoming Intent.

Step one - Create a send-method that the sender uses.:

```
public final static String ACTION_SEND_NAME = "com.example.intent.action.SEND_NAME";
public final static String ACTION_SEND_NAME_EXTRA = "name";

public static void sendPackageName(Context context, String name) {
    if (null == context || null == name) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument(s) may not be null");
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SEND_NAME);
    intent.putExtra(ACTION_SEND_NAME_EXTRA, name);

    //You might add extra these flags
    intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    //LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    //context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    //context.startService(intent);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Step two - Modify the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Other Intent filters -->
            <action android:name="com.example.intent.action.SEND_NAME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Step three - Modify the receiving entity:

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//...

// Get intent, action and MIME type
Intent intent = getIntent();
String appName;

if (ACTION_SEND_NAME.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    appName = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.ACTION_SEND_NAME_EXTRA); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have only one question. Is this for sending single string or an ArrayList?

Comment: That is for a single string but you can change it to ArrayList and use putParcelableArrayListExtra() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29

Comment: I have done that. For that only I am using finalList.add(packageName) and its giving me nullpointerexception. Please have a look at above code and tell me what I am doing worn. Thanks.

Comment: Change declaration to ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. It works very properly. But I didnt understand. Could you explain me what is difference between writing just 
ArrayList<String> finalList and 
ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Declaration just specifies what type your variable is. You need to instantiate an object for that variable before dereferencing the field. So: Declaration does not automatically create an object, you need to specify it as well.

Comment: Thanks it shows the package name in my other activity. Any idea how I could start the app when its package name is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by sending an intentExtra to the activity that you want.

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourOtherClass.class);          
in.putExtra(TAG_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
startActivity(in);
```

Then in the "YourOtherClass", get the value by calling :

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String packageName = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PACKAGE_NAME);
```

Hope that helps :)

**EDIT:**
To send a list , ArrayList , you can use :

```
in.putStringArrayListExtra("listOfValues", yourArrayList);
```

and get it using

in.getStringArrayListExtra(listOfValues);

Comment: But this will send a single packageName right? I wanna many apps to other activity.

Comment: I get what is happening here but I am not sure how to send an ArrayList<String> instead of just one packageName. Please help

Comment: Yes thats what. I have done that only. As you can see in the code I posted, when an item is clicked I am adding it to an String ArrayList finalList by the code finalList.add(packageName) and it is giving me java.nullpointerexception when I click on an item. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have tried this for single packageName and it works properly. Please tell me how to get rid of nullpointerexception. Do you want me to post my code? Please help.